# Why does VS Code show type information from JSDoc for var but not for other members in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

The following intellisense discrepancy in Visual Studio Code leaves me puzzled:

```
function ExampleModule() {

    /** @type { string } */
    this.myMember; // tooltip shows 'any'

    /** @type { string } */
    var mySecondMember; // tooltip shows 'string'
}
```

I would like to add type information to my modules via *JSDoc*, which works well for some situations like method signatures and apparently it works for variables declared with the `var` keyword, but not if I add the member to my object as shown with the `this` keyword.

I've looked at the documentation, specifically [this document about supported JSDoc comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript), but they don't seem to explain why `this.myMember` doesn't generate intellisense information.

Is there any way of improving the shown type information for members or does more detailed information on supported language constructs exist?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how class notation works.
First you define a composite type, then you use it for your vars.
I don't know if you can define "this" type.

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} ExempleModule
 * @property {string} myMember
 */

/** @type {ExempleModule} */
```